# Can you beat every Tax Collector game?

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic, factoring, conjectures

There's a one-player math game called Tax Collector, and recently I was intrigued by it. Let me explain the game, and then I'll ask my question.

> To start, choose a number to be your ceiling - the game will use all numbers from $1$ to $x$, where $x$ is your ceiling.

> Then, claim a number to add to your score. The Tax Collector then claims all the factors of that number, and adds them to their score. Claimed numbers cannot be taken again.

> Note that you cannot take a number with no unclaimed factors. This means that you can only take one prime number at most (with a factor of $1$), and all the others are guaranteed to go to the Tax Collector.

> The game ends when you cannot claim any numbers, and all the unclaimed numbers go to the Tax Collector. Whoever has a greater total wins.

I started wondering if this game could ever be impossible to win. Instantly, I realized it could be - if your ceiling is $1$, then you can't take anything and the Tax Collector wins, $1$ - $0$. However, because you don't have a chance to make a move, I considered the game with a ceiling of $1$ to not count as a real game. So the question moved to $2$ and upwards.

I was stopped once again by the game with a ceiling of $3$, as it also proved impossible to win. Your two options were to pick $2$ or $3$ - picking $3$ was the better choice. Then, you get $3$ points, the Tax Collector gets $1$ point, and the Tax Collector gets two as well, since it has not factors left. Final score: $3$ - $3$.

However, after this, I tried greater numbers, and the games were always beatable, usually by a rather large margin. So here's my question:

**After the games with ceilings $1$ and $3$, are there any ceilings that leave the game impossible to beat, no matter how well you play?** I would assume no, since the prime numbers get scarcer as the numbers get larger, and primes are the Tax Collector's main source of income. However, I don't know how to prove that all games to infinity are beatable - and maybe there's an unbeatable one out there!

I would really appreciate help with this question. Maybe there's something obvious I'm not seeing, but I feel like this is more complicated than the game is itself.

Comment: The ceiling part is irrelevant , let us just start with the numbers from $1$ to $x$ where $x$ is a positive integer. Upto which $x$ could you completely analyze the game ? Does a draw count as a loss ? Can the game go on forever (In this case, there is apparently no winner) ?

Comment: “Only one prime” - does the prime itself not count as a factor, so you mean “proper factors”?

Comment: @Peter - a draw is not a loss, it just means you can't win either, which is what I'm asking about. Also, I don't think the game can go on forever, because on every turn at least two numbers are claimed (one for you and at least one for the Tax Collector).

Comment: @gnasher729, A prime number is a factor - I mean that the Tax Collector is guaranteed to end up with all but one prime (or all of them) because you can't claim any primes after your first one. The Tax Collector could get them as factors of the number you claim, or at then end if they are unclaimable.

Comment: You cannot win for 7 too.

Comment: @XZCY 7, 4, 6. Win 17-11. (The exact order is important.)

Comment: I've manually checked for all numbers up to 13 - but I could write a program (albeit a dumb one since I'm a very amateur programmer) to check higher numbers.

Comment: I made a python program to check with a plausible strategy. I had it run until x=1000, and it only failed to win for 1,3 and 8. 8 can be 'healed' by just using another strategy there, and at the end the scores where roughly 1.5 times that of the Tax Collector, so not really close. So it looks plausinle it is true, but of course that's not really a proof.

Comment: Thanks @Ingix! As I was manually solving a few numbers, I noticed that often I would choose the same numbers in the same order, with a few minor tweaks as the number increased. For example, I did the exact same thing for 8 that I did for 7, except for one move where I chose 8 instead of 4. I don't know if there could be some way to use a proof by induction in this manner...?

Comment: Inducttion is not likely to work, IMO. That's because after the first choice the problem does not transform into one for $x-1$, or something similar, it's a totally new list of numbers.

Comment: Yeah... still it seems like the best way to start, even if it doesn't work in the end.

Comment: @Ingix - I wrote a program on Python too, and it must have used a similar strategy since 8 failed to succeed as well. I did notice that by 1000, the differences in score between the player and the TC were enormous - I would hypothesize that these differences only grow bigger, but again, I have no way to prove it,

Comment: Describing the maximum score gets tricky because of cases like $\{30,50,75\}$ where you can claim any two of the numbers but never all three. (I know, you don't need maximum scores to prove games are winnable.)